# An HTTP GET Request Returns of 302, but the Location Header is the Same As the One I Originally Passes

Tags: python, http, ssl, https, websocket

I am receiving an unexpected response from a server that I don't know how to fix. I have been tinkering with the Discord Gateway, which uses a secure websocket connection. However, when I request to establish a connection, to the gateway, I get a `302 Found` response status. After a bit of googling, I discovered that I should use the URI specified in the `Location` header; however, this was (nearly) identical to the one I originally passed.

```py
import socket
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()

ssl_sock = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname='discord.com')

ssl_sock.connect(('discord.com', 443))

ssl_sock.sendall(b'''GET /wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json HTTP/1.1\r
Host: discord.com\r
Authorization: Bot uhfu734\r
User-Agent: Disc ($https://hi.com, $2)\r
Upgrade: websocket\r
Connection: Upgrade\r
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==\r
Origin: https://discord.com/\r
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat\r
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n\r
''')
print(ssl_sock.recv(10000))
```

Here is the response:

```py
b'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nDate: Wed, 02 Sep 2020 01:21:26 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nSet-Cookie: __cfduid=d6941593b4b04a8b370e7a4c7799155d81599009686; expires=Fri, 02-Oct-20 01:21:26 GMT; path=/; domain=.discord.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure\r\nLocation: https://discord.com/wss:/gateway.discord.gg?v=6&encoding=json\r\nStrict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\nX-Frame-Options: DENY\r\nX-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nocache, noimageindex, noodp\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\ncf-request-id: 04ee009aad0000cf1c8304e200000001\r\nExpect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"\r\nServer: cloudflare\r\nCF-RAY: 5cc36a0aab6dcf1c-IAD\r\n\r\n'
```

The only difference in the location header is the `/` right before the `?`, but when I omit it, I receive a `401 OK`. As you can see, the `Location` header is nearly the same as the URI I originally used, so I don't know what else to do from here.

For information specific to the Discord API, you can read here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway. I have already read it, but it's possible that I misinterpreted something.

Please do not lead me in the direction of the `websockets` library, I know it's great for this purpose, but my goal is to understand some of the underlying concepts of websockets, and to do so, I prefer to interact with them with less abstraction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you get URL with `/` then use this URL - it can make big difference for server. But more important can be that it sends `Cookie` which you have to use in next request(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> GET /wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json HTTP/1.1
> ```

This is likely not a valid request. It looks like you are mixing up protocol, method and path in a strange way.  It should likely be:

```
GET /?v=6&encoding=json HTTP/1.1
```

Your strange request is likely what causes this strange response.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. I took your advice, and received a `200 OK` response. While this is definitely better than a 302, I was expecting a `101 Switching Protocols` after reading about websockets here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 . I am not sure why I'm receiving a 200 here, and I would be grateful for some clarification. The reason I am expecting a `101` here is because of the `Upgrade` Header.

Comment: @hipeople321: This is a different question and should be asked as a new question. But in short: it looks like you mainly cut+paste the GET from the WebSocket RFC (including the key), no matter if the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` even makes sense in your specific context. Before implementing it by your own I suggest you rather use an existing websocket library.